# Trocar classe de input quando este estiver preenchido

Tags: javascript, jsf, primefaces

Estou fazendo um formulário utilizando primefaces, e queria que meu input trocasse de classe quando estivesse preenchido, só voltando a classe anterior caso o usuário apagasse o conteúdo. Isso é para fazer com que o outputLabel saia de dentro do input e fique vísivel conforme a figura que anexei.

> A primeira figura é como é inicialmente;
>   A segunda figura é como é pra ficar;
>   A terceira é como está ficando.

Alguém sabe um jeito de fazer isso? o meu aqui não está dando certo...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Se entendi bem a sua dúvida, a forma de fazer isso usando Primefaces é com Watermark. Veja aqui: https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/misc/watermark.xhtml

Comment: Luan, poste o código também, fica mais fácil de analisar, inclusive o código que vc está tentando.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode fazer uma verificação no blur do input.

Veja qual a classe existente na label quando ela fica em cima do input (com o efeito que vc quer) e faça o seguinte:

**SE ESTIVER USANDO JQUERY**

```
$('#selector_input').on('blur', function(){
    var _self = $(this);

   if(_self.val() != null){
      $('#selector_label').addClass('class-do-efeito');
   }else{ 
      $('#selector_label').removeClass('class-do-efeito');
   }
})
```

**SE ESTIVER USANDO JAVASCRIPT PURO**

```
var input = document.getElementById('id_input');
var label = document.getElementById('id_label');

input.onblur = verifyInput(input);

function verifyInput(input){

   if(input.value != null){
      label.classList.add('class-do-efeito');
   }else{
      label.classList.remove('class-do-efeito');
   }
}
```

Comment: Não estou usando jquery :(

Comment: @LuanSilva atualizei a resposta com a solução usando javascript puro. Boa sorte ;)

Comment: ainda não funcionou!! acho que pode ser o lugar onde estou colocando... é preciso chamar essa função?? E eu ponho onde? num script dentro da mesma página ou em outro externo (se fazer diferença)

Comment: @LuanSilva, atualizei o código novamente. Veja se agora funciona :)
Você pode colocar num arquivo externo (se já houver um) ou no mesmo arquivo, como é um código relativamente pequeno, recomendo colocar no mesmo arquivo (tag script antes do fechamento do body).

Comment: ta quase lá... ele já está vindo com a classe mesmo sem ter nada escrito

Comment: Poderia postar o seu código no JsFiddle? Acho que seria melhor para dar suporte

Comment: Já consegui resolver... obrigadão!!

Answer (score 0):

Se for apenas trocar a classe do `input` (conforme pergunta), use `oninput` (o `oninput` é mais eficiente porque detecta quaisquer alterações no campo):

```
<script>
    var el = document.querySelector("#id_do_input");
    el.oninput = function(){
        this.value ? this.classList.remove('nome_da_class') : this.classList.add('nome_da_class')
    }
</script>
```

Exemplo:

```js
var el = document.querySelector("#id_do_input");
el.oninput = function(){
   this.value ? this.classList.remove('nome_da_class') : this.classList.add('nome_da_class');
}
```

```css
.nome_da_class{
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<input placeholder="Nome" type="text" class="nome_da_class" id="id_do_input" />
```

Comment: não tem o "oninput" pro inputText do primefaces

Comment: @LuanSilva Atualizei a resposta. Abs!

Comment: Eu consegui resolver mudando o seu onInput pra onChange... Está funcionando. Obrigado!